# Converting arrays to linked lists en masse

Tags: java, arrays, junit, linked-list

I'm currently writing a JUnit test that requires a Tree Map as an expected value.

Said TreeMap looks like this:

```java
Map<Integer, LinkedList<String>> expected = new TreeMap<>();
```

I filled said Tree Map with the data that should return from the Test:

```
    expected.put(1, (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("18_2_2_3_java.lang.String_", "27_0_0_93_java.sql.Timestamp_", "256_6_6_0_java.lang.String_", "200_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "8_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "4_2_2_5_java.lang.Integer_", "5_6_6_5_java.lang.Short_", "23_0_0_93_java.util.Date_", "5_0_0_5_java.lang.Integer_", "35_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "20_6_6_0_java.lang.String_", "19_0_0_12_java.util.Date_", "12_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "112_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "1_0_0_5_java.lang.Short_", "4_0_0_2_java.lang.String_", "7_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "3_0_0_5_java.lang.Integer_", "0_6_6_5_java.lang.Boolean_", "-1_0_0_2005_byte[]_", "19_6_6_1_java.lang.String_", "3_0_0_4_java.lang.String_", "4365_6_6_93_java.sql.Timestamp_", "0_6_6_5_java.lang.Integer_", "23_6_6_93_java.sql.Timestamp_", "1_250_250_12_java.lang.String_"));
    expected.put(2, (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("2_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "-1_6_6_2005_java.lang.String_", "20_0_0_12_java.lang.Long_", "25_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "2_6_6_5_java.lang.Integer_", "500_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "5_6_6_5_java.lang.Boolean_", "128_6_6_0_java.lang.String_", "512_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "6_2_2_3_java.math.BigDecimal_", "25_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "4_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "19_6_6_0_java.lang.String_", "12_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "1_6_6_5_java.lang.Boolean_", "2_0_0_5_java.lang.Short_", "50_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "0_6_6_0_java.lang.Boolean_", "0_0_0_5_java.lang.Boolean_", "-1_6_6_-1_java.lang.String_", "4_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "10_0_0_4_java.lang.Boolean_", "80_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "20_8_8_3_java.math.BigDecimal_", "18_3_3_3_java.math.BigDecimal_"));
    expected.put(3, (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("150_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "0_6_6_0_java.sql.Timestamp_", "0_6_6_0_java.lang.Integer_", "1_0_0_5_java.lang.Boolean_", "32_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "4_0_0_93_java.sql.Timestamp_", "2_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "0_6_6_91_java.util.Date_"));
    expected.put(4, (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("1024_6_6_1_java.lang.String_", "-1_6_6_-4_byte[]_", "30_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "27_6_6_93_java.sql.Timestamp_", "40_0_0_12_java.lang.String_", "2_6_6_5_java.lang.String_", "2_2_2_5_java.lang.Short_", "2_0_0_4_java.lang.Integer_", "2000_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "120_6_6_12_java.lang.String_", "4365_6_6_93_java.util.Date_", "256_6_6_12_java.lang.String_"));
//There is a lot more but you get the point
```

As some of you maybe already have noticed; the Lists are wrong.
They have to be Linked Lists.

Eclipse recommended Type Casting the List to a Linked List which is what I tried, but that didn't work out.

I'm pretty lost on this one.

Comment: Why `LinkedList` and not a `List`? Normaly there is **no** reason to limit yourself to a single list implementation. And if you really need the values as `LinkedList`, then just use the appropriate constructor - `new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(values here))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lance-java's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78148301/3788176) would work, but they are quite cumbersome.

I would suggest defining a method like this:

```
public static LinkedList<String> linkedList(String... values) {
  return new LinkedList<>(List.of(values));
}
```

and then invoke this in your test:

```
expected.put(1, linkedList("18_2_2_3_java.lang.String_", "27_0_0_93_java.sql.Timestamp_" /* etc */);
// etc
```

It's just a bit neater.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitly try it. What does `(String...` do? I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: @th0sf4n variable number of arguments of type string.

Comment: To clarify, variable number of trailing arguments (`String...values`) in Java are implemented as a single array. Which means you can actually pass an array in the last argument position if you have one, rather than individual parameters.

Comment: @th0sf4n see ["Arbitrary number of arguments"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) in the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```java
LinkedList<String> list = Stream.of("one", "two", "three").collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

or

```java
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(List.of("one", "two", "three"));
```

Comment: The first creates a `LinkedList`, the second creates a default (probably array) `List`, then creates a `LinkedList` from that.

Comment: The first creates a `Stream` backed by an array then collects it into a `LinkedList`. The second creates a `List` backed by an array (likely `ArrayList`) then creates a `LinkedList` from that

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse recommended Type Casting the List to a Linked List which is what I tried, but that didn't work out.

```
expected.put(1, (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("18_2_2_3_java.lang.String_",
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ~ !!
```

You cannot cast an ArrayList to a LinkedList. You need to create a new LinkedList and pass the list to the constructor like this:

```
expected.put(1, new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("18_2_2_3_java.lang.String_", "27_0_0_93_
```

For a more in depth reference, see implementation of [Arrays.asList](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2827).

You may also use [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) instead of Arrays.asList.